# Libgdx get pressure of touch event

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am developing a pressure sensitive game on android. (Or with other words the game is finished)
But know i want to start using a game engine and i decided to use Libgdx. 
However the GestureDetector.GestureListener and the InputProcessor Interface do not provide the pressure parameter from the android internal MotionEvent. 
I tried to manually set the Game as a View.OnTouchListener but that is interfering with the threading model ...

any suggestions for a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one option so far i know i.e `getPressure()` from `MotionEvent` class. the function will give you the value between 0 to 1 in float.[docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)

Note : Device without pressure sensor simulate pressure by the size of touch point.

**More pressure means more area of screen covered by finger**.

`setOnTouchListener` can give you `MotionEvent` object from which you can get the pressure value like.

```
someView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float pressure = event.getPressure();
    }
});
```

Comment: thx but you answer is concerning general MotionEvents but has nothing to do with Libgdx but i found an answer to my question
thx anyways

Comment: good you found it , but it doesn't mean MotionEvent is not used for simulating pressure by Libgdx plus you should also share your better way with community so it will benefit others who come around your quesstion if you like

Comment: as you can see in the next answer I already posted my solution ;-) 
and to the point that MotionEvent is not used for simulation pressure by Libgdx:
I believe we have a little communication problem. Libgdx does not provide a pressure parameter/variable in its EventStructure
that is what i meant with MotionEvents do not have anything to do with Libgdx. Libgdx does take the MotionEvents and restructures them internally and removes the pressure information. That is the reason why I needed a work around: adding manually a touchlistener and manually pass invoke the onTouch event.

Answer (score 2):

Here is part of my code for adding the pressure to a game object

```
final MyGdxGame game = new MyGdxGame();

    View view = initializeForView(game, config);
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            getInput().onTouch(v, event);
            game.setPressure(event.getPressure());
            Log.v("log", "hooked " + event.getPressure());
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The trick is that I have to call `initializeForView` in order to overwrite the `onTouchListener` and forward the `MotionEvent` to the Input Handler of `Libgdx`.

Comment: you asked for this ,`However the GestureDetector.GestureListener and the InputProcessor Interface do not provide the pressure parameter from the android internal MotionEvent` and it's given. anyway it's good to see, you have done it,+1

Comment: please EDIT your Q and put the code there. not as an answer here